# woopsie-upload-all process consumes cpu 100%

Tags: bug-reporting

My ubuntu environment is the below

```
$ uname -a
Linux jae-pc 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
```

After recent update, my notebook's fans began to run loudly.

So I checked processes, `woopsie-upload-all` process consumes a core 100%.

I disabled the bug report ("Send error reports to Canonical") feature, but  it doesn't  100% prevent woopsie-upload-all process running. Sometimes the process starts by itself and doesn't stop...

Where should I check to prevent run woopsie-upload-all elsewhere?

And it seems woopsie-upload-all has some bugs

Comment: If you are sure it's a bug, then please report it to the bug tracker. (AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker)

Comment: Bug has been created and confirmed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/whoopsie/+bug/2018996

Answer (score 12):

You probably have some processes creating crash-reports with large files. Look in `/var/crash/` if there are some big crash-reports. When those are being uploaded to canonical it can produce a high system load.

On my system I had a 361MB file:

```
_usr_bin_baloo_file.1000.crash
```

So `baloo`, the kde search-assistant created a problem.

I don't need `baloo` on my Ubuntu system (it was installed as a dependency packet when I installed KDE `dolphin`) so I disabled it with

```
balooctl disable                  # stops the service
rm -rf .local/share/baloo/        # removes the index files; they can be several GB
```

and delete the crash reports with

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*baloo*
```

Comment: I was able to delete the crash file while whoopsie was still using 100% CPU and that "fixed" it. This happens rarely so I am happy with that solution. Thanks for posting the details I needed.

Answer (score 8):

Uninstall the `whoopsie` and `apport` services. These are crash reporting services which can face issues.

```bsh
sudo systemctl stop apport
sudo systemctl stop whoopsie 
sudo systemctl disable apport
sudo systemctl disable whoopsie
sudo apt-get remove apport whoopsie
```

Comment: This is not a solution, it is just a workaround and probably hides the real problem. Usually you want to keep error reporting on so problems on your system become visible.